# How can I set what will be done when my python program terminates with error?

Tags: python

Is there any method to set certain action when my python program ends abruptly?
Especially I want to delete a folder and leave a log what was the error using logging module.

Comment: There's a few options you can do. One is just putting a try/except block around your main function that is called, another is to use the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module.

Comment: Do you know what causes the abrupt end?  Is it always the same cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "ends abruptly", the `atexit` module https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use error handling, particuarly using the Try, Except statements.